# Чем бы отобразить очень большой текст?

Tags: javascript, html, ajax, веб-программирование

Привет всем! Подскажите, пожалуйста такой вопрос: стоит задача отображать огромный текстовый файл на веб-странице. Есть идея делать это Javascript с Ajax. Соответственно, есть необходимость в неком скриптовом компоненте, который бы отображал лишь текущий фрагмент файла. А вот когда юзер скроллит текст вниз или вверх, тогда бы компонент Ajax'om подкачивал бы очередной фрагмент файла с сервера (на сервере Java+JSP+Spring). Я видел скрипты наподобие фейсбука - они разворачивают контент, когда юзер скроллит вниз. А я бы хотел, чтоб он работал и вверх и  вниз, и чтоб текст не накапливался. В фейсбуке когда скроллишь вниз, верхняя часть контента не исчезает, а мне надо чтоб она очищалась и вновь подкачивалась, если юзер скроллит вверх. Также желательно, чтоб компонент позволял вообще переходить в произвольной место текстового файла.

Есть ли такие компоненты  в природе?

Comment: _..верхняя часть контента не исчезает, а мне надо чтоб она очищалась и вновь подкачивалась, если юзер скроллит вверх._ Зачем очищать, чем она вам мешает?

Comment: браузер не треснет отображать например гигабайт текста?

Comment: Ну так он же у вас не сразу целиком будет отображаться, а по частям. И я с трудом представляю себе юзера, скроллящего гигабайт текста в течение одной сессии.

Comment: По сути у вас стоит задача разбить текст на части, части хранятся наверняка в БД. Первое что может «треснуть» это хранилище. Вы же не будете каждый раз разбивать текст в памяти? Как разбивать? Допустим запрос. Далее нужно создать некий хэндлер, который будет выдавать куски текста, ваша задача следить за событиями скролла и подгружать в конце страницы новый кусок, добавляя массив параграфов в DOM и удаляя старые (думаю разумно будет хранить несколько экранов). Общее количество экранов можно выдавать вместе с каждым блоком, что бы выводить блок полного размера.

Comment: К чему я это? К тому что задача слишком специфичная для хранилища. Нужно еще как-то обрабатывать произвольный скролл и нивелировать разницу в высоте экранов. Так что можно декомпозировать задачу и оформить в виде нескольких вопросов.

Comment: Так как найти такой компонент не удалось, пришлось написать самому. Я его выложил в инет, возможно кому-нить еще пригодится http://polyakoff.ucoz.net/